# AutoMapper: Converting a tree to an entity list

Tags: c#, automapper

I have "Source" classes and "Destination" class:

```
public class ActionSource
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PlaceSource> Places { get; set; }
}

public class PlaceSource
{
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<EventSource> Events { get; set; }
}

public class EventSource
{
    public string Event { get; set; }
}

public class EventInfoDestination
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
}
```

How can a map ActionSource data to `IEnumerable<EventInfoDestination>` with AutoMapper?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much auto about this mapping. You should do it by hand. AM would only get in the way.

```
    from place in source.Places
    from ev in place.Events
    select new EventInfoDestination { Action = source.Action, Place = place.Place, Event = ev.Event};
```